# vuejs handle input change in loop

Tags: vue.js

My question is if I am doing the below code correctly or is there a better way? I want to handle the change in any input values.

I have an object of options:

```js
customOptions: {
  1:"test 1",
  2:"test 2",
  3:"test 3",
}
```

and I am showing them in the template like this:

```html
<div class="custom_options">
  <div
    class="row-fluid flex form-row"
    v-for="(option, index) in customOptions"
    :key="index"
  >
    <span>{{ index }}</span>
    <span>
      <input :value="option" :id="index" @change="handleChange" />
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and finally my method:

```js
handleChange(event) {
  Vue.set(this.customOptions, event.target.id, event.target.value)
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use `v-model` like `<input v-model="customOptions[index]"/>` :

```html
<div
  class="row-fluid flex form-row"
  v-for="(option, index) in customOptions"
  :key="index"
>
  <span>{{ index }}</span>
  <span>
    <input v-model="customOptions[index]"/>
  </span>
</div>
```